# What Parts of a SQLite Statement Can Have Bound Parameters?

Tags: sqlite

What parts of a SQLite statement are able to take bound parameters? For instance, I have discovered that the following is invalid:

```
SELECT @column1 FROM @table WHERE @column2 = @criteria
```

The only parameter in the example that I've been able to get to work properly is `@criteria`, leading me to think that only values on the right hand side of an equation can be bound as a parameter.

I'm having a hard time finding an answer for this in the [official documentation on bound parameters](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) and my searching on the internet, so could anybody please tell me definitively what parts of a SQLite statement can be bound?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That documentation says:

> literals may be replaced by a parameter

A [literal value](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#litvalue) is:

> a constant of some kind. Literal values may be integers, floating point numbers, strings, BLOBs, or NULLs.

Table and column names are *not* strings (although SQLite sometimes allows you to use the same syntax for compatibility with MySQL).

Comment: Thanks, I guess the wording, and the fact that I wasn't familiar with the phrase "literal", made it difficult for me to figure out.